# Django complex json response for ohlc dataset

Tags: python, django, charts

I'm trying to pull my data at json response in Django views to make simple financial ohcl chart https://github.com/MarcinLinkl/chartjs-chart-financial
To do this, I need the following js structure:

```
    const data = {
      datasets: [{
        data: [
        {
          x: 1647280800000,
          o: 1,
          h: 0.75,
          l: 0.75,
          c: 1.25
        },
        {
          x: 1647281700000,
          o: 1.20,
          h: 1.5,
          l: 0.75,
          c: 0.9
        },{
          x: 1647282600000,
          o: 1.20,
          h: 10.5,
          l: 0.75,
          c: 10.9
        },{
          x: 1647283500000,
          o: 12.20,
          h: 14.5,
          l: 12.75,
          c: 10.9
        }
        ],
      }]
    };
```

But I can't send that by context, or even make view with a JsonRespone like :

```
def apidata(request):
    data = {{
          x: 1647280800000,
          o: 1,
          h: 0.75,
          l: 0.75,
          c: 1.25
        },
        {
          x: 1647281700000,
          o: 1.20,
          h: 1.5,
          l: 0.75,
          c: 0.9
        },{
          x: 1647282600000,
          o: 1.20,
          h: 10.5,
          l: 0.75,
          c: 10.9
        },{
          x: 1647283500000,
          o: 12.20,
          h: 14.5,
          l: 12.75,
          c: 10.9
        }}
    
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

```
TypeError at /api-data/ unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How could I send this data like structure to template (might by with ajax) (and ofcourse for getting latter some dynamic data)

Comment: the keys in the dict are all `variables` whereas they need to be `strings`. Also `JsonResponse` is not defined.

Comment: Yes that's right, but I need to make data structure in without quotation mark, how could I do it?

Comment: valid `json` syntax rules are clear. Here is a convenient example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Send the data like this,so the json can be formated.

```
data = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]
```

Django doc: [json](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/)